# Unable to cast object of type grouping to datarow after i grouped datatable with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hi basically i wanted to group my datatable by the department column, i want to load the results back into another datatable through looping but it keeps giving me an error, im not sure how to group a datatable with linq and load it into another datatable other than looping

here is my code

```
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                data.Columns.Add("Department");

                var query1 = dtClone.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("department"));
                if (query1.Any())
                   foreach(DataRow dr in query1)//here
                    {
                        DataRow newrow = data.Rows.Add();
                        newrow.SetField("Department", dr.Field<string>("department"));
                    }

                foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                    MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
```

another linq query i tried

```
               DataTable data = new DataTable();
                data.Columns.Add("Department");
                var query1 = from r in dtClone.AsEnumerable()
                             orderby r.Field<string>("department") ascending
                             group r by r.Field<string>("department") into r
                             select r;
                if (query1.Any())
                   foreach(DataRow dr in query1)
                    {
                        DataRow newrow = data.Rows.Add();
                        newrow.SetField("Department", dr.Field<string>("department"));
                    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add all possible departments in separate table?

Comment: @GaurangDave Dont think so no, i just want a datatable of the departments because the first datatable which i am querying against consists duplicate departments

Comment: I think that is what I told. You want a separate datatable with all departments in it. Now question is do you want duplicates or distinct?

Comment: @GaurangDave oh yes its i want to load the results of the query in a seperate datatable, distinct departments

Comment: No need to group in that case.  Try `var query1 = dtClone.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("department")).Distinct();`

Comment: @GaurangDave oh thanks it works, but how do i order the data? i only know how to do ordering with a query expression.  and can you add it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to group data in case of getting distinct records (only one column).

```
var query1 = dtClone.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("department")).Distinct();
```

ORDER BY

```
var query1 = dtClone.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("department")).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s);
```